# How to package an angular module with translations so it can be reused

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

How can you package an angular module with its own translations stored in json files, without harming or needing extra config from the host app? This module should be able to exist as a bower dependency.

Basically I want the templates (directives) in my module to set the correct values, based on the $translate.use() of the main (ng-app) module. This without any concatenating of files or special config required by the main app. This would allow me to quickly add the module to various applications. You would just include the module in your app config angular.module('my-app', ['my-translated-module]); and it would be able to render the translations correctly as soon as you're starting to use the directive. The config of the translation is of course in the config section of 'my-translated-module'

For example: think of a login form with a "sign up" and "login" button. I want to have it this as a separate module/directive, so different applications could reuse that part, without having the duplicate the translations. If the module gets an update, i just need to do a bower update on my main app, rerun

I'm on angular 1.5 and using the angular-translate library by pascal precht - with the static file loader.

Comment: If you JUST "include the module in your app config angular.module('my-app', ['my-translated-module])" - angular-translate will not JUST work. You need to add 1) configuration section ; 2) $translate service in controllers; So it's unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: hi shershen - thanks for your time! - i edit my question to make it more clear. the config section should be in the 'my-translated-module', the $translate.service should be able to switch the language of anything that is using translations no matter if you are in a controller or main app.

basically: think of it as a module of an external vendor that has translations provided - and would obey to the $translate service for language switchting

Comment: would be even better if you could pus minimal viable code example on http://plnkr.co/